# Create a navigation drawer inside a Router component defined inside react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to create a navigation drawer like this below using the "react-native-router-flux" library components:
[image]

And I want the "hamburger" menu icon as well like this:
[image]

I went through multiple stackoverflow questions and other articles but I couldn't figure out a way to create this drawer. I was able to display the Hamburger menu icon, but was not able to create the drawer which has multiple options.

My code:

```
const navBarButton = () => {
    return(
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.refresh({ key: 'scene2', open: true })}>
        <Icon 
            name='three-bars' 
            size={30} 
            color='#000' 
            onPress={() => Actions.aboutUs()}
            />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}const Routes = () => {
    
    return(
    <Router renderLeftButton={navBarButton}>

        <Scene key ="root">
            <Scene key = "scene1" title = "scene1" component = { scene1 } initial = {true} />
            <Scene key = "scene2" title = "scene2"  component = { scene2 } />
        </Scene>

    </Router>
    );
}
export default Routes;
```

What more components do I need to create and how should I integrate them with the existing code to create a navigation drawer?

==============UPDATED CODE=========

```
import SideMenu from 'react-native-side-menu';
import Home from './components/Home';
import AboutUs from './components/AboutUs';
import {Scene, Actions , Drawer, Stack} from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default function NavigationDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer
          hideNavBar = {true}
          key="drawerMenu"
          contentComponent={SideMenu}
          drawerWidth={300}
          drawerPosition="left"
          drawerIcon={
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Actions.refresh({ key: 'home', open: true })}>
                <Icon 
                name='three-bars' 
                size={30} 
                color='#000' 
                onPress={() => navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            }
        >
          <Stack key="mainContainer">
            <Scene
              key="home"
              component={Home}
              title="Home"
              navigationBarStyle={{
                backgroundColor: "black"
              }}
              navBarButtonColor={"blue"}
            />
            <Scene
              key="aboutUs"
              component={AboutUs}
              title="AboutUs"
              navigationBarStyle={{
                backgroundColor: "black"
              }}
              navBarButtonColor={"blue"}
            />
          </Stack>
        </Drawer>
  );
}
```

Comment: The latest production version of `react-native-router-flux` uses React Navigation 4.x, so it should be safe to follow the React Navigation [docs for drawer navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-based-navigation/).

Comment: But this library won't give me the hamburger icon for navigation menu, right?

Comment: To add icons look at [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: No actually I meant, where should I add the component of Hamburger icon to make it visible on all screens? I am referring to this code right now: https://rb.gy/0lcepe

Answer (score 2):

This is the implementation of Drawer in react-native-router-flux.

```
        <Drawer
          hideNavBar
          key="drawerMenu"
          contentComponent={SideMenu}
          drawerWidth={300}
          drawerPosition="left"
          drawerIcon={<DrawerIcon />}
        >
          <Stack key="mainContainer">
            <Scene
              key="homeScreen"
              component={HomeScreen}
              title="Home"
              navigationBarStyle={{
                backgroundColor: TABS_BACKGROUND_COLOR
              }}
              navBarButtonColor={MAIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR}
            />
            <Scene
              key="societiesScreen"
              component={SocietiesScreen}
              title="Societies"
              navigationBarStyle={{
                backgroundColor: TABS_BACKGROUND_COLOR
              }}
              navBarButtonColor={MAIN_BACKGROUND_COLOR}
            />
            ...
          </Stack>
        </Drawer>
```

This is the function for opening the drawer.

```
_showDrawer  = () => {
    return () => {
            Actions.refresh({key: 'drawerMenu', open: true });
};
```

Comment: Hey, I edited the code above in the question which I Implemented by using your code, but I didn't get anything. The screen is blank.